# Usage of IAdapterFactory with popupMenus in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My requirement was to add a new menu entry to “Compare with” present in one of the 3rd party views. 
As this was using “org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus” to add a menu entry to the above contribution. Even I was forced to use the same extension point even though its deprecated.
I was able to add a menu entry to the contribution with the below code

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
         <objectContribution
               adaptable="true"
               id="test.id"
               objectClass="local.change">
        <action
              class="compare.commparetool"
              enablesFor="1"
              id="id"
              label="Compare "
              menubarPath="compareWith/group1">
         </action>
        <visibility>
           <objectState
                 name="local.change"
                 value=".txt">
           </objectState>
        </visibility>
</extension>
```

The above configuration is working fine.
Next requirement was to add property tester to hide the menu entries whenever a file selected is other than .txt file.
As we cannot add property tester to object contribution, I have used `IAdapterfactory`. Below code is not working.

Observation:
I have added many menu entries (“org.eclipse.ui.menus”) in different views in “Compare with” which is not related to this. 
But if user clicks on any of these commands, and then try the view in question, it is working as expected as expected.

Below is the code. Am I missing anything. Do I need to register the adapters in some other place also??

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters">
      <factory
            adaptableType="local.change"
            class="LocalChangeAdapterFactory">
         <adapter
               type="org.eclipse.ui.IActionFilter">
         </adapter>
      </factory>
</extension>
```

```java
public class LocalChangeAdapterFactory implements IAdapterFactory
{
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public Object getAdapter(final Object adaptableObject, final Class adapterType)
  {
    if (adapterType == IActionFilter.class)
    {
      return LocalChangeActionFilter.getInstance();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public Class[] getAdapterList()
  {    
    return new Class[] { LocalChangeActionFilter.class };
  }
}

public class LocalChangeActionFilter implements IActionFilter
{

  private static LocalChangeActionFilter INSTANCE = new LocalChangeActionFilter();

  private LocalChangeActionFilter()
  {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean testAttribute(final Object target, final String name, final String value)
  {
    String fileName = "";
    if(target.getId==1){  
        return true;
    }else{
    return false;

  }

  public static LocalChangeActionFilter getInstance()
  {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `adaptableType` attribute of the adapter factory should specify the type of the existing object that you want to adapt to an IActionFilter. So this is probably a resource of file:

```xml
   adaptableType="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
```

The `getAdapter` method of the `IActionFactory` should return a class matching the `adapter` attribute, not your implementing class:

```java
public Class[] getAdapterList()
{    
  return new Class[] { IActionFilter.class };
}
```

Your `testAttribute` method if the action filter must test the `name` parameter matches the value in the `objectState`:

```java
@Override
public boolean testAttribute(final Object target, final String name, final String value)
{
   if (name.equals("local.change"))
    {
      .... do test

      return true;
    }

  return false; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg,
Thanks for replying!!! I changed all the code as u suggested, same issue still persists.
Issue :: The adapter is not getting called for the first time. User has to click on some other commands and  then if the user go back to this view and click on any file the adapter will be called.

Comment: I  think your `objectClass` also needs to be 'org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource'